# Function is not running.. I have 2 functions one of them is working properly but second one is not doing its work

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects, dom-events

This is the first function and its working properly and doing its work.

```
 function p2Others(valNum) {
      valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
      var tempkg = valNum/2.2046;
      var kg = tempkg.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById("kilograms").value = kg;
      document.getElementById("ounces").value = valNum*16;
      var tempg = valNum/0.0022046;
      var g = Math.round(tempg);
      document.getElementById("grams").value = g;
      var tempstone = valNum*0.071429;
      var stone = tempstone.toFixed(3);
      document.getElementById("stones").value = stone;
}
```

This is the second one. I don't know what's wrong with this function. I tried everything but it is still not working....

```
 function KG2Others(valNum) {
   valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
   var temppounds = valNum*2.2046;
   var pounds = temppounds.toFixed(2);
   document.getElementById("pounds").value = pounds;
   document.getElementById("ounces").value = valNum*35.274;
   document.getElementById("grams").value = valNum*1000;
   var tempstone = valNum*0.1574;
   var stone = tempstone.toFixed(3);
   document.getElementById("stones").value = stone; 
}
```

Actually there are many functions but these two are are from the same block of div which is about weight conversions.

Comment: if you debug in developer tools, you can step through each one to find out what the problem is

Comment: can you explain what "it is not working" means please?

Comment: How you are trying to call this method?

Comment: using oninput and onchange in a input tag.@Virushabadoss

Comment: `VM9283 pen.js:190 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at KG2Others (VM9283 pen.js:190)
    at HTMLInputElement.oninput (jyjMEd:629)
KG2Others @ VM9283 pen.js:190
oninput @ jyjMEd:629`

Now this happens... Unable to undestand !

Comment: are you sure you have an element on your DOM with an id of "pounds"?